# Only select ID if certain conditions apply

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I only want to select a client ID if the client status is equal to 1 (active) on the latest (!) timestamp; if not, than do not show it.

I am able to get the relative latest timestamps where the client is active, but that is not what I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share code you are using;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()`

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE status = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
                 WHERE t.client_id = s.client_id
                   AND s.timestamp > t.timestamp)
```

Of course all this names are a guess due to lack of information on your question, so adjust it to your data.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Give a row number based on `clientId` and descending order of date column.
Then,

**Query**

```
select t.ClientId, t.`status`, t.`timestamp` from
(
    select ClientId, `status`, `timestamp`, 
    (
        case ClientId when @curA 
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curA := ClientId end 
    ) as rn 
    from your_table_name t, 
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    order by ClientId, `timestamp` desc
)t
where t.rn = 1 and t.`status` = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the latest timestamp relative to the client_id, or for the entire table?

Depending on which, I would comment / leave uncommented line from this:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table t
WHERE status = 1
AND timestamp =
( SELECT MAX(t2.timestamp)
  FROM your_table t2
  WHERE t2.client_id = t.client_id //comment this line
);
```